# Jetty Static resources dont respect the file permission (read specifically) when listing

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I have a simple xml context to display static files.  The server loads fine and the page to show files loads as expected.  The issue is that file with permission 000 are still showing in the list.  If I click on one of the files I get a java stack trace error saying that jetty does not have permission to read the file (because it doesnt).

Does anyone know how to get these files with no read permission to not show up?

I am using jetty distribution version 9.4.34.v20201102.  I run jetty as a service and have JETTY_USER set in /etc/default/jetty.

Here is my simple context in JETTY_BASE/webapps/static.xml

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="resourceBase">/mshr/test/</Set>
      <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the Jetty ResourceHandler, the ResourceService, or the DefaultServlet.

Asking about file permissions during file listing is actually quite an expensive thing to do (depending on the file system).

That's why Jetty doesn't do that.

If you feel otherwise, file a request at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues